# Automate Connect-AzureAD in DevOps using Self Hosted agent not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to AD by running simple Powershell command in Azure DevOps. The same code running on my local machine after installing self signed certificate. But same command not running and giving error -

```
The certificate certificate does not have a private key
```

I have installed certificate in windows machine which is there in the backend.

Code I am running -

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId xxx -ApplicationId xxx -CertificateThumbprint xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's working on local machine but failed on DevOps only, please follow below items for a check:

1. Double check the parameter value for `connect-AzureAD` command in DevOps, make sure tenantid, app id, and CertificateThumbprint is correct.
2. On agent machine, try to renew the certificate, will it report it doesn't have private key?

[image]

Try to regenerate the self-signed certificate following official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-testing-only--create-and-upload-a-self-signed-certificate)  with command below and update to azure service principal, and `connect-AzureAD` command.

```
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=DaemonConsoleCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
```

3. Make sure your devops agent user(add `whoami` command in pipeline to get) is same with your local account.

I created self-signed cert and it works on devops on my side:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rohi_Dev_1.0, may i know if there's any update? Please follow above steps for a check, let me know if you have any queries.